# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
select buses.bus_no,
       buses.bus_name 
from   buses 
join 
(
    select sc1.bus_no 
    from   schedule as sc1 
    join   schedule as sc2 on  sc1.source = sc2.destination 
                           and sc1.destination = sc2.source
) as s1 on buses.bus_no = s1.bus_no;
```

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: Turn `as s1` into `s1`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support `as` for table aliases.  So, you can write this as:

```
select b.bus_no, b.bus_name 
from buses b join 
     (select sc1.bus_no 
      from schedule sc1 join
           schedule sc2
           on sc1.source = sc2.destination and sc1.destination = sc2.source
     ) s1 
     on b.bus_no = s1.bus_no;
```